# Imagem cortada ao comparilhar no facebook

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

Oi, eu tenho um botão de compartilhar no facebook as notícias do meu site. Ele pega a imagem correta, o titulo correto e a descrição correta. Mas quando a janela aparece no feed de notícias no facebook a imagem vem cortada aparecendo só um pedaço da imagem. Já pesquisei bastante e não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

eu tenho isso:

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.meusite/upload/noticias/thumbs/d6524bc2eb6956b3345fc4f401b2f182.jpg">
 <meta property="og:title" content="Titulo">
 <meta property="og:description" content="Descrição">
 <meta property="fp:app_id" content="xxxxx">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

primeira imagem é a janela antes de compartilhar

segunda imagem é depois que compartilho.

Comment: qual a dimensão da imagem? a recomendação é que para imagem ser exibida perfeitamente tanto para desktop, mobile e tablet a proporção seja de 1.91 ex: 1200×627 se a imagem não chegar a 400×209 o facebook redimencionará ela para 154×154 ou 90×90

Comment: as imagens sempre são maiores que o que o facebook diz, elas tem sempre entorno de 3000 x 1875 pra mais.

Comment: Proporção de 3000 x 1875 está 1,6. Você não consegue alterar a proporção para 1,91?

Comment: não, eu não sou o encarregado pelo upload da imagem, é o usuário direto no admin do site.

Comment: na verdade não sei, acho que rola alterar com algum código php, mas dai já nao sei.

Comment: tenta primeiramente alterar a resolução da imagem para proporção de 1.91. verifica se o facebook ainda vai cortar a imagem.